# How to search the folder's items in ArcGIS Online using the ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I want to have a list of the items inside a folder created by my user in AGOL, I want to use the ArcGIS API for Python.

so far I have found this:

```
import sys
from arcgis import gis
import os

sourceURL="https://yourAGOL.maps.arcgis.com"
sourceAdmin="adminUser"
sourcePassword="thisIsNotMyPassword"

clientAcronym = "Sales"
source = gis.GIS(sourceURL, sourceAdmin, sourcePassword)
existingItems = source.content.search('title:"{0}*" '.format(clientAcronym))
```

this code list all the items where their title start with Sales, but I know there is a folder called "Sales-Test" and it has some of those items, i want to know which items are inside of that folder:

if I get the list of my folders

```
me = source.users.me
me.folders
for folder in me.folders: 
    print(folder['title'])
    me.items(folder['title'])
```

I can see the folder "Sales-Test" but not he items inside it

In the Item [documentation](https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.gis.toc.html?highlight=folder#item) i cannot see how to get the folder information.
Is there a way to relate the information of existingItems with me.folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what if you add this:

```
    me = source.users.me
    me.folders
    for folder in me.folders: 
        print(folder['title'])
        me.items(folder['title'])
        itemsInFolders = me.items(folder=f['title'])  
        print(len(itemsInFolders))
        for i in itemsInFolders:
            print("      " +str(i.title))
```

Comment: could you please format your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work but was not getting all results.  Turns out there's a default of 100 items returned max.  I had to explicitly change that to see everything:

```
folder_items = user.items(folder=folder['title'],max_items=1000)
```